# Tracking mouse position in Adobe Air using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, air

How do I track the mouse cursor position change in Adobe Air using Javascript API in Adobe Air 1.5? The following code doesn't seem to work for me.

```
var mainWin; //main stage
var _self={};
_self.mouse={x:0,y:0};

//Alias: air.MouseEvent=window.runtime.flash.events.MouseEvent;
mainWin.addEventListener(air.MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,function(e){
    _self.mouse.x=e.pageX;
    _self.mouse.y=e.pageY;
});
```

What I want to implement is IM-like status change Ready to chat/Away. If there is another way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.idleThreshold = 10; //10 seconds idle time

air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(air.Event.USER_IDLE, function(event) { 
            //away
    }); 

air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(air.Event.USER_PRESENT, function(event) { 
            //back
    });
```